# Liquibase throws "SQLException: connection is closed"

Tags: mysql, liquibase, jhipster, liquibase-hibernate

```
   ERROR [kernel-Executor-1] liquibase:
      classpath:config/liquibase/changelog/00000000000000_initial_schema.xml::00000000000001::jhipster:
      Could not release lock liquibase.exception.LockException:
      liquibase.exception.DatabaseException:
      liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLException:
      Connection is closed
              at liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService.releaseLock(StandardLockService.java:250)
              at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:216)
              at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:192)
              at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:434)
              at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:391)
              at com.vadict.kernel.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.initDb(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:66)
              at com.vadict.kernel.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$0(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:49)
              at com.vadict.kernel.async.ExceptionHandlingAsyncTaskExecutor.lambda$createWrappedRunnable$1(ExceptionHandlingAsyncTaskExecutor.java:47)
              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException:
      liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLException:
      Connection is closed
              at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.rollback(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1143)
              at liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService.releaseLock(StandardLockService.java:242)
```

I am getting this error while running my liquibase script. How to resolve it?

Comment: post the full log please. I think that there is an error before this errors ocures.

Answer (score 4):

There is probably some migration lock stuck into database and no new migration scripts can be launched. Truncate table `DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK` to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

If the database is the newest, you can try to delete all the tables in the db. liquibase will re-create it for you.